# How do I access device camera in GameMaker Studio 1.4?

Tags: android, camera, ios, game-maker

I've looked everywhere in the documentation for GameMaker and I didn't find anything about how to access the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GameMaker doesn't have native support for device cameras, that's the reason you didn't find anything about it in the docs.

On the other hand, you can try to access the webcam on desktop devices using DLL libraries, like the one mentioned [in this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamemaker/comments/63k8mg/any_webcam_plugin_for_gms/), or looking for some plug-ins.